# Rearrangeable cardviews in Androidstudio and more than one Cardview in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-cardview

1)How can you make an Activity in Androidstudio where you can rearrange 5-6 cardviews, just like in Windows 10 Startmenu?

[Example Activity (Windows 10) with views you can rearrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a95ba.png)

2)How can you make an Activity with more than one Cardview (just like the picture above (windows 10 Startingmenu))?

Any Tipps would be very appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it .You need to use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager 
and in the end you  to set span size for your List

First set specify the no of columns you need in a grid in your case it is 2

```
     gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
```

Then check the position of the View and set the span size accordingly

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {

            //depanding upon the type of data  set the span-size if it is header take the whole space in the row
            //also check the orientation and set the span-size
            if (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == Adapter.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
            // if the type is item type keep the span-size as normal which is one
            if (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position) == Adapter.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
```